# Ao rodar dois projetos Django ao mesmo tempo, um dos dois usuários é deslogado

Tags: python, django, login, navegador-de-internet

Estou trabalhando em dois projetos que compartilham o mesmo banco de dados, e assim os mesmos usuários, mas são dois projetos diferentes em servidores diferentes.

A questão é que, ao acessar os dois ao mesmo tempo (tanto localmente quanto no servidor), o usuário do projeto que não está sendo acessado é deslogado e é necessário logar novamente.

Assim, é mais uma questão sobre como funciona o sistema de autenticação do Django nesse caso, se utiliza alguma variável do navegador ou algo assim e por isso não suporta os dois ao mesmo tempo. Já pesquisei mas não sei bem como pesquisar essa situação.

Projeto 1 - Django 1.10.1 e Projeto 2 - Django 2.2.1

Ambos estão utilizando os mesmos middlewares (não entendo muito disso, utilizei os padrões)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Quais são os middlewares que as aplicações está utilizando?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a pergunta e adicionei os middlewares, os dois projetos estão utilizando os mesmos

Comment: O *Django* persiste a informação de usuário logado no banco de dados (tabela `django_session`) e se como as aplicações estão compartilhando é bem capaz de uma estar "sabotando" a outra. Faça um teste com o _login_ em cada versão e verifique o que se registra na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, como está no comentário do Giovanni, as informaçoes sobre sessão e login de usuário são guardadas em banco de dados pelo middleware de Session do Django. Como são o mesmo banco, e sem nenhuma confiuração adicional, e um uso inesperado (ao contrário, por exemplo, de o mesmo usuário estar logado a partir de browsers diferentes no mesmo sistema - um caso bem mais comum), o middleware está se embananando.

Olhando rapidamente no código do Django, parece que a parte que invalida a Session de outro sistema no mesmo banco vai ser esse trechinho aqui:

```py
        except Exception as e:
            # ValueError, SuspiciousOperation, unpickling exceptions. If any of
            # these happen, just return an empty dictionary (an empty session).
            if isinstance(e, SuspiciousOperation):
                logger = logging.getLogger('django.security.%s' % e.__class__.__name__)
                logger.warning(str(e))
            return {}
```

(em `django.contrib.session.backends.base.py` ~linha 110) -
Se olhar os logs dos sistemas deve dar pra ver o warning logado acima. )

Aparentemente esse não é um cenário esperado mesmo no Django - o middleware de Session não prevê uma forma de se alterar o nome da tabela usado pelo banco, por exemplo. Se em um dos sistemas você puder mudar de sessões em banco para outro tipo - com a configuração do [session engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#session-engine), deve resolver seu problema.

Se quiser manter a Session em banco para ambos, o remédio vai ser criar sua própria classe de session.engine, herdando justamente de `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore` - e na sua classe herdade, você modifica o método `get_model_class` para uma *outra* classe que você deve herdar de `from django.contrib.sessions.models.Session` - e nessa sua `Session` herdada, você altera a informação de Meta.db_table`.  Aí você aponta para o módulo, dentro do seu projeto, onde criou a nova classe`SessionStore`na configuração`SESSION_ENGINE` do seu settings.

Em suma, dentro do seu projeto, um arquivo que vai ficar algo como:

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as BaseSessionStore
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session as BaseSession

class Session(BaseSession):
    class Meta(BaseSession.Meta):
         db_table = "sistema_y_django_session"


class SessionStore(BaseSessionStore):
    @classmethod
    def get_model_class(cls):
        return Session
```

E aponte esse arquivo no `SESSION_ENGINE`